# detecting value crossing between columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 'b': [0, 10, 40, 45, 50]}, columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

I would like to make a list of indices where:

> a [i - 1] < b[i] and a[i] >= b[i]

in order to detect when a value, in a timeseries, is crossing another one

is there a Pandas idiomatic way to achieve this without iterating through all the elements?

I tried to create a new column with flags to indicate a crossing by doing this:

```
df['t'] = (df['a'].shift(1).values < df['b'].values and di['a'].values >= df['b']).astype(bool)
```

but that won't compile. I'm not sure how to approach this problem, short of doing a loop through all the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) which is *"less than"*, same as `<` and [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) which is "greater than or equal" and is same as `>=`:

```
mask = df['a'].shift().lt(df['b']) & df['a'].ge(df['b'])
# same as (df['A'].shift() < df['b']) & (df['a'] >= df['b'])

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Notice, we don't have to specify `astype(bool)`, pandas works with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and returns `booleans` when defining conditions.

---

To get the `indices` of the rows with `True`, use:

```
idx = df[mask].index.tolist()

print(idx)
[4]
```

Comment: thanks! is there any way to get a list of the indices where the statement is true?

Comment: Could you explain why'd you want that? Do you want to return these rows which are `True`?

Comment: the code is used to detect crossing points in financial data; at that stage, it leaves the Pandas world since actions need to be taken for each of these events, with the index/timestamp as a parameter

Comment: I see, added it to my answer. But I barely have to return a list of indices when using pandas. The solution you have in your head probably has a better approach, but that's outside the scope of this question for now. Glad I could help and good luck @Thomas

Comment: Why shift only `df['a']` rather than `df['a'].lt(df['b'])`? Doesn't that compare prices from different days?

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution would be to use a condition in combination with [Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html): This will basically test where you condition changed.
I like this because I feel it is a little easier to read, it also might be a little faster.

***NOTE***: you need to convert the type of the condition to **int** otherwise you get True for changes up and downwards (pandas .diff uses xor for bool instead of sub, see link above)

**Find the positions where df.a crossed df.b upwards:**

```
mask = df.a.gt(df.b).astype('i1').diff().gt(0)
```

or if you find this easier to read:

```
mask = ((df.a > df.b).astype('i1').diff() > 0)
```

**output:**
[image]

```
# to get the index
idx = df.loc[mask].index
```

**output:**
[image]