# track state reversal in Pandas by comparing two columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-on to my previous question: [detecting value crossing between columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399896/detecting-value-crossing-between-columns-in-pandas/59399980?noredirect=1#comment104989497_59399980)

Let's assume I have two columns, `df['a']` and `df['b']`, called 'a' and 'b' here to simplify

In the previous question, I was trying to detect indices where: a[i - 1] < b[i] and a[i] >= b[i]

now, I am trying to track two changes:

```
a[i - 1] < b[i] and a[i] >= b[i]
```

and

```
a[i - 1] >= b[i] and a[i] < b[i]
```

and create a column with a value set based on the LAST change that occurred.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
state = 0
result = []
for i in myIndex:
    if a[i - 1] < b[i] and a[i] >= b[i]:
        state = 1
    elif a[i - 1] >= b[i] and a[i] < b[i]:
        state = 0

result.append(state)
```

is there an idiomatic (non-looping) way to achieve this in Pandas?

---

Edit:

I realize this question has caused some confusion, so I didn't word it properly. An example here:

Let's assume I have two columns for the outputs of the two conditions I'm tracking:

```
 cond_A    cond_B
 false     false
 false     true
 false     false
 false     false
 true      false
 false     false
```

then the output should be (if we set 0 and 1 as output values):

```
cond_A    cond_B    output
false     false     0
false     true      1
false     false     1
false     false     1
true      false     0
false     false     0
```

so, if both conditions are false, we reuse the last state, if a condition is true, we set the state.

Comment: Rather than including pseudocode, have you tried writing a solution yourself based on the answer to your previous question? That would be a good place to start, then you can ask a specific question if you get stuck, since "Can someone write this code for me" is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stack overflow

Comment: @G.Anderson, his "psudocode" is nearly runnable code, given a dataframe. I think that's a bit harsh.

Comment: yes, the code runs in a loop, but it's slow. I'm trying to figure out if there is a faster way without having to query all the elements one by one. Since I'm not very experienced with Pandas, I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be harsh, and I apologize if it came off that way. However the answer provided in the linked question gives code to solve nearly this exact problem in a loop-free, idiomatic way using `.shift()` so it's not clear how this question is different from the previous question

Comment: the main difference is that I want to keep the last state between the two conditions: so if condition 1 is true, set the state to 1 for example, and if condition 2 is true, set the state to 0 and fill the output with the last state; in some rows, neither condition will be true so the last state must be used

Comment: could you show the expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question and put some sample output

Comment: ummm a lifelong flip flop

Comment: Is it possible to make the result of each iteration either a value decided by a set of conditions (like what is in the previous question, but 2 conditions) or the same column with a shift, to recover the previous result?

Comment: It is possible with a little imagination and math :) check my solution! I'm glad I found a simple solution for this problem

Comment: @ansev: very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the equation of a RS flip flop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

using the example given as a dataframe:

```
print(df)

   cond_A  cond_B
0   False   False
1   False    True
2   False   False
3   False   False
4    True   False
5   False   False
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
df['state']=df.any(axis=1).where(df['cond_B'].cumsum().ge(1),0).cumsum()%2
print(df)


   cond_A  cond_B  state
0   False   False      0
1   False    True      1
2   False   False      1
3   False   False      1
4    True   False      0
5   False   False      0
```

---

If you have two independent series

```
(cond_A | cond_B).where(cond_B.cumsum().ge(1),0).cumsum()%2
```

Comment: it's interesting, I was exactly thinking of it as a flip-flop too! (I suffered several years of VHDL..). The solution is very nice! thanks!

Comment: I have studied electronics for years and also program in VHDL :). Finding a simple solution in pandas for this has excited me a lot, since I thought I was not able to get rid of the loops!. I am glad to help you:) 
thanks for asking this question

Comment: In case the state is 0, if it produces a True to set the state to 0 the previous solution would fail, I have taken this into account and updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
>>> df['c'] = pd.Series((df.a.shift(-1) < df.b) & (df.a >= df.b)).replace({False : 0, True : 1})
>>> df
    a   b  c
0   8  17  0
1   2  86  0
2  93  42  0
3  49   1  0
4  35  62  0
5   3  39  0
6  25  21  0
7  54  24  1
8   3  77  0
9  41  42  0
```

Comment: it is not necessary to use `pd.Series` here, instead of `replac`e you can use `astype (int)` or `np.where`