# is there an idiomatic panda way to get indices from 2 lists that represent a start and stop signal

Tags: python, pandas

I have lists like this:

```
index   A        B
0       false    true
1       false    false
2       true     false
3       false    false
4       false    false
5       false    false
6       true     false
7       false    false
8       false    true
9       false    false
10      false    false
11      true     false
12      false    false
```

the output I need is (2, 8)

the logic is that once a true has been detected in A, I will look for the next true in B, ignoring any other true in A

in practice it would do that:

```
index   A        B
0       false    true   // ignore the true in B
1       false    false
2       true     false  <- start
3       false    false
4       false    false
5       false    false
6       true     false  // ignore the true in A
7       false    false
8       false    true   <- end
9       false    false
10      false    false
11      true     false  <- start again
12      false    false
```

so I can do it in a loop (pseudocode):

```
for i in a.index:
    for j in b.index[i + 1:]:
        if b[j]:
            # write i and j somewhere
            i = j
            break
```

It is pseudo code because the i = j line will not work

Is there a panda-ish solution to implement this?

It is very similar to my previous question ([track state reversal in Pandas by comparing two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400530/track-state-reversal-in-pandas-by-comparing-two-columns/59400721)) but the main difference is that, once a start (column 'A') has been detected, I want to ignore all of them until there is a stop (column 'B')

The fastest 'loop' solution I have found so far is:

```
i = 0
while i < len(A):
    start = A[i:].idxmax()
    stop = B[start + 1:].idxmax()
    print(start, stop)
    i = stop
```

Comment: Is it possible for a True to be in B column before the true in A?  And do you only want the first occurrence or will you expect multiple start/stop ranges from a dataframe?

Comment: yes, good point! yes, it can be and it has to be ignored. Essentially 'A' is a start and 'B' is a stop.

Comment: @ScottBoston: I've added a true at the beginning of the dataset to illustrate the scenario

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [False, True, False, True]
b = [True, False, False, True]

if True in a:
    aNum = a.index(True)
    bNum = b[aNum:].index(True) + aNum if True in b[aNum:] else None
else:
    aNum = None
    bNum = None

print((aNum, bNum))
```

#### Output

```
(1, 3)
```

Comment: how would this work in a loop? you can see on the test data that the cycle restarts at row 11

Comment: I would put it in a generator so you can continue to step through the rest of the data.  See my 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modification to the previous answer to allow continuation:

```
def getNextPair(aTotal, bTotal):
    curPos = 0
    while True:
        a = aTotal[curPos:]
        b = bTotal[curPos:]

        if True in a:
            aNum = a.index(True)
            bNum = b[aNum:].index(True) + aNum if True in b[aNum:] else None
            if aNum is not None:
                aNum += curPos
            if bNum is not None:
                bNum += curPos
        else:
            aNum = None
            bNum = None

        if aNum is not None or bNum is not None:
            yield((aNum, bNum))

        if bNum is None:
            break

        curPos = bNum + 1


a = [False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
b = [True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, False, True]
for startStop in getNextPair(a, b):
    print(startStop)
```

#### Output

```
(1, 4)
(5, 6)
(8, 9)
```